# How to cancel any changes to textbox data

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm creating my own version of a wizard form using Asp.Net Webforms.

The form contains multiple steps and each step contains multiple input fields of varying types. Data is validated after each step is completed before moving onto the next step.

In addition to moving forward, each completed section also has an Edit facility.

I was hoping to have 2 buttons available in Edit mode - one to Continue and re-validate and another to Cancel and forget everything.

However, it seems that isn't so easy.

The continue button works exactly as the Continue button in add mode - in fact it's the same button - so no issues there.

But there is an issue with the Cancel button.

Suppose a user enters edit mode and changes their name from 'John' to 'Jon'. They could press Continue to accept and revalidate. however, if they were to press Cancel, they would expect so see the original spelling of 'John' restored.

This doesn't happen automatically.

So, as I currently see it, I have two options. The easy option - remove the Cancel button (and potential confusion) - or the hard option, to code a backup and restore solution in edit mode, which is likely to be a pain as it will need to cover all input types.

However, I'm hoping there's a third option available - one that offers some kind of built in functionality to help manage this problem.

So that's the question - is there any other solution aside from the two options I've already outlined?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're stuck with the hard option. Afaik there's no built-in 'undo' with unbound controls. Maybe there's an addon/extender available?

Comment: Not that this will be any easier, but I found [this](https://addyosmani.com/blog/mutation-observers/) on mutation observers. MDN also has a [writeup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).